# Rigol Arbitrary Waveform Generator DG1022Z and Square Signal Sample Rate

Tags: signal, uart, measurement, function-generator

I have generated simple arbitrary function which represent UART message, but I'm having trouble when it comes to decoding it on oscilloscope.

The reason for that is because my 0 and 1 at frequency of 9600Hz (in order to match 9600 baud) does not look like digital (square) signal.

That was because when I was generating the signal for example for letter "H" (binary "01001000") and with little endian format and start and 2 stop bits "00001001011" I saved this as appropriate 0v and 5v in *.RAF file.

So, in order to get square signal I have to multiply number of 0 and 1, for example: "00001001011" to "000000000000111000000111000111111" ...

So, my question is, is this appropriate solution, or there's some other option on generator which I can use to solve this initial issue.

Comment: try sending U where U is Hex 55 or binary 0101 0101 or similar

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 How is this related to anything in my question?

Comment: You probably don't want to set the frequency to 9600 Hz.  Generally the ARB is set up to assume the whole trace is one period, and you want to play that back 9600 times per second.  What you need to do is set the frequency to 9600 / (length_in_data_bits) Hz.  Or set the sample rate, if the instrument lets you specify that.

Comment: @Shp  You ought to know how UART clock sync works with 16x clock then delays 1x clock by 1/2 bit to center sample.  The ARB has a preset phase shift and external trigger so if you use a square wave character like U, you have chance of getting Scope sync with 1x clock. Once ext trigger and delay are set,  inter-character delays need a start byte clock again for n bits per byte. Capiche? or a proper cct to do the Async Start bit detect for scope clock sync. It's not that hard to create a start bit and data clock for ASYNC data.

Comment: @alex.forencich instrument support both, frequency and sample rate, but my question was, what would be sufficient sample rate then which would be good enough to generate square signal without data overhead in *.raf file?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 this has nothing to do with start - stop bits, generating initial signal is simple, add start bit, add data bits, add parity and stop bits (1 or 2) etc. Re-arange them so that less bit goes on first place and most significant bit on last place. And that will give me a valid binary TTL message. In order to translate this further to RAF file which generator can import, I need to transform these zeros and ones into appropriate voltage by assigning values from 0 to 16k (in my case for 5v from 8k to 12k for my device DG1022Z) and put them in hex file.

Comment: Can you not use an easier method e.g. SIPO to old PC Parallel port? Or a FILO register to UART then code Byte 1 * Byte 2 in an Arduino using double precision.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I know it is weird usage and that this is not very practical. :) But that's not the question. I'm just exploring the ability of arbitrary function generator in order to see how can be used to simulate digital (TTL) signal. And who mentioned anything about Arduino? I'm talking about generating plain simple TTL message via arbitrary function which I want to verify later with logic analyzer or oscilloscope, that's it.

Comment: oohh pleisioasynchronous EBCDIC data, rots of ruck

Comment: Professor: "So the American government went to IBM to come up with an encryption standard, and they came up with—"
Student: Reverse ASCII

Answer (score 1):

To get digital output from an ARB you would have to disable the output filter.  I looked through the manual on the Rigol DG1022Z and there does not seem to be a way of doing that - the way you are currently doing it seems to be the best.

BTW you should put the manufacturers name and what it is in the question, other people may not know it is a Rigol Arbitrary Waveform Generator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin, and how about this "duplication", I couldn't find what's the "magic" number for that, what would you recommend? I mean, in the sample above I just used 3 (111 for one 1 and 000 for one 0), but I'm guessing there must be a proper way for that

Comment: The more you duplicate the values the more "square" the output will be.  If it works with 3 there is little point in doing more.

Comment: Ok, and once I have proper (visual) look for that square, any hints on how to adjust generator so that I can be able to decode the signal on oscilloscope? I mean, beside setting the frequency to 9600Hz for 9600 baud and VHigh to 5v and VLow to 0v.